# C to C# PInvoke with structs with pointers

Tags: c#, c, pointers, struct, pinvoke

I'm trying to create a C# interface which receives a callback from an external C DLL.
The callback's parameters contain pointers to C structs, which themselves have a pointer to a different struct.

The callback signature:

```
typedef application_event_result (*application_event_ptr)(abuffertype* read_buffer, abuffertype* write_buffer);
```

The buffer struct definitions in C:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16 size;   
    uint8* data; 
} anotherbuffertype;

typedef struct {
    anotherbuffertype *buffer; 
    uint16 position; 
} abuffertype;
```

I know that the C# signature of the callback should use "ref" for the pointer type of the parameter. But how can the pointer inside the "abuffertype" struct be defined in C#?

So far I have this definition of the two structs in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct anotherbuffer
    {
        UInt16 size;
        IntPtr data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct abuffer
    {
        anotherbuffer buffer;
        UInt16 position;
    }
```

But that doesn't work. The contents of "abuffer" in C# is not what was there before the callback in the C code.

Do I need to unmarshal the internal struct pointer manually, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get help from the marshaller, this normally causes a major memory management problem.  But can work in the specific case of a callback since it is the calling C program that manages the data.

You have to convert the data yourself.  Declare the pointers as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to retrieve the data.

The anotherbuffertype.data member looks like an array, use `Marshal.Copy()` to copy its content into your own byte[] array.  If you don't mind the `unsafe` keyword then you can keep it declared as byte* and access the elements with data[index], avoids the cost of the copy.  It is not very unsafe, pretty easy to keep index constrained to [0..size).