# How to correctly parse IntPtr to Object in C# when marshaling from C++

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, intptr

I'm invoking a C++ function from within C#.
The function I am trying to invoke returns following C++ struct type result:

```cpp
LPWFSCIMNOTETYPELIST lpNoteTypeList;

typedef struct _wfs_cim_note_type_list
{
    USHORT usNumOfNoteTypes;
    LPWFSCIMNOTETYPE *lppNoteTypes;
} WFSCIMNOTETYPELIST, *LPWFSCIMNOTETYPELIST;

typedef struct _wfs_cim_note_type
{
    USHORT usNoteID;
    CHAR cCurrencyID[3];
    ULONG ulValues;
    USHORT usRelease;
    BOOL bConfigured;
} WFSCIMNOTETYPE, *LPWFSCIMNOTETYPE;
```

I found the suitable struct in C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = XFSConstants.STRUCTPACKSIZE, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct WfsCimNoteType
{
    public ushort usNoteID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public char[] cCurrencyID;

    public uint ulValues;
    public ushort usRelease;
    public byte bConfigured;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = XFSConstants.STRUCTPACKSIZE, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct WfsCimNoteTypeList
{
    public ushort usNumOfNoteTypes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public WfsCimNoteType[] lppNoteTypes;
}
```

I used the following code to parse the result from invoked function:

```cs
WfsCimNoteTypeList data = new WfsCimNoteTypeList(); 
XFSUtil.PtrToStructure<WfsCimNoteTypeList>(lpBuffer, ref data);
```

(here `lbBuffer` is `IntPtr`)

`XFSUtil.PtrToStructure` is defined like this:

```cs
public static void PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr, ref T p) where T : struct
{
    p = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
}
```

But after parsing from `IntPtr` to `WfsCimNoteType` object array, I am getting different values???

Comment: Without knowing what's in `XFSUtil.PtrToStructure` and where you get `lpBuffer` from, this'll be difficult to troubleshoot. I will say that with semi-complicated structures like these (directly involving variable-sized structs) it tends to make a lot more sense to have some C++/CLI code to glue the unmanaged and managed worlds together; ideally you want your C# code be able to just work with a `List<WfsCimNode>` or suchlike instead of having to mess around with these low-level types. For example, giving the `lppNoteTypes` a constant size of 20 looks very fishy/wrong.

Comment: Do not use a comment for posting more code, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)` is wrong. `_wfs_cim_note_type_list` only has a pointer to `_wfs_cim_note_type`(s), it does not include its/their body in itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39587090/11683.

Comment: LPWFSCIMNOTETYPE *lppNoteTypes; is a pointer which is only 4 bytes. and equivalent to IntPtr.

Comment: @jdweng It's either 4 or 8 depending on the bitness of the process

Comment: @Mansur Presumably `CHAR` is a macro evaluating to `char`. That's an 8 bit type, but your C# code uses `char` which is a 16 bit type. You probably need to use `byte` in the C# there. The other problem is `lppNoteTypes`. That's a pointer to an array of length `usNumOfNoteTypes`. You can't use `ByValArray` there. Likely that you will need to use `IntPtr` and then manually marshal the contents of the array. Exactly how to do it depends on the direction of flow of data, how it must be allocated etc. In short, there is not enough detail in the Q to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David Heffernan, it was useful. I declared lppNoteType to IntPtr, but all values come wrongly. 

`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = XFSConstants.STRUCTPACKSIZE, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public unsafe struct WfsCimNoteTypeList
        {
            public ushort usNumOfNoteTypes;
            public IntPtr lppNoteTypes;
        }`

Comment: You have to fix all of the issues and you didn't address the wider points that I made. Also it is pointless to use unsafe and packing looks wrong.