# Is there any downside to using unmanaged structs by ref?

Tags: c#, struct, unmanaged, ref

In many api samples we get IntPtr as a pointer to structure, and I see that people allocate new memory, copy all data, and then create a new structure as I understand it. Or they use Marshal.PtrToStructure (). What is the difference in using Marshal.PtrToStructure() and just ref Struct? In case I just need to read some structure data.

```
[DllImport("some.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetPoint(IntPtr point);

delegate IntPtr GetPointDelegate(IntPtr point);

// assing function that will be invoked
GetPointDelegate callback = ConsumePoint;

// delegate implementation
IntPtr ConsumePoint(IntPtr ptr)
{
    Point point = (Point)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Point));
    // do stuff with point
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

```
[DllImport("some.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetPoint(ref Point point);

delegate IntPtr GetPointDelegate(ref Point point);

GetPointDelegate callback = ConsumePoint;

IntPtr ConsumePoint(ref Point point)
{
    // do stuff with point
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

How is this different?
Is this translated to the same thing? Or is it more efficient in the second way but there are some dangers when using it?

Comment: If your `GetPoint(ref Point point)` is the `[DllImport]`ed method, then yes, you can use `ref Point point` if the marshaler is able to understand your structure. [Otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39587090/11683) you will have to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, I have edited the question little bit.

Comment: I don't understand the code you posted. You seem to be declaring both `GetPoint(IntPtr)` and `GetPoint(ref Point)` twice, once as `DllImport` (i.e. p/invoke), and once as C# code. This normally would result in a compile-time error, because the methods have the same signature. What is the C# version of the method supposed to be illustrating? The implementation of the `DllImport` method? Or the consumption of it? Or something else? Please fix your question so that it isn't confusing.